# How do you get a custom tag value in JQuery when you have multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you get a custom tag value?  In this case it would be "customtag".  I thought you could do this with prop or attr?  All I get is "undefined".

JQuery

```
var value = $("button[customtag]").prop();
var value1 = $("button").attr("customtag");
alert(value);
alert(value1);
```

HTML

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-link status_change' customtag='something' >Active</button>
<button>something</button>
```

Comment: The `value1` works fine. Delete `value` variable and `alert(value)` and it should work properly.

Comment: You should be using custom data attributes `data-customtag`

Comment: Only if there's only one `<button>` in all the document and it has a `"customtag"`, @Kinduser.

Comment: I still get undefined with value1 even when I remove value commands.  I have many buttons per page.  So what am I missing?

Comment: Really? I don't. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rrnL406b/

Comment: @j08691 Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/sw7h3tnL/

Comment: Andrei Gheorghiu showed my exact dillema, but I wonder what I need to change in jquery to fix this.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I have already given you the answer, above. You need to only select the buttons that have the custom attribute set, with `$('button[customtag]')`. And go through the collection using `.each()`. With only the code you provided there's no way one could understand your app/page logic and what you're trying to do. Or, if you're only intrested in first one, use `$('button[customtag]').eq(0)`

Comment: var value1 = $("button[customtag]").attr("customtag");   Awesome!  I see how I had to combine both commands together.

Comment: What about just binding a click event on each button? https://jsfiddle.net/m8592ey7/

Comment: I updated the title of the question to be more clear, because in this case more than one button does change the way JQuery behaves, even though in the beginning I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your custom data attribute name should start with "data-" to make it an HTML5 compliant attribute. However, you can still access your customtag with a non-standard naming the following way:

```js
var value1 = $("button").attr("customtag");
console.log(value1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' customtag='something' >Active</button>
```

If you have more than one button element in your HTML, you can access this "Action" button with an ID.

```js
    var value1 = $("#actionButton").attr("customtag");
    console.log(value1);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="actionButton" type='button' customtag='something' >Active</button>
```

Comment: @Kinduser, did you even run the code snippet before down voting? It works and addresses OP's question.

Comment: The OP already stated in the comments this solution (which has already been suggested), doesn't work.

Comment: How can you be so sure that I've downvoted you? What if we have more buttons than this only specified one?

Comment: Next time try to give an informed answer by also reading the comments. Most times they provide additional, valuable information. If you're interested in providing a helpful answer, that is, of course.

Comment: @Kinduser, you can access the element with an ID too if there are multiple elements of the same type in your HTML.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, or how about trying to find a fault in others' answers rather than contributing to one's answer to make it complete? Is that what you do?

Comment: Still not really clever, but good enough to remove my downvote.

Comment: You might notice I've tried to be helpful to the OP explaining them what they did wrong. You might also notice I've also tried to be helpful to you, by telling you what I think you did wrong. It looks like my advice is not appreciated. I guess I'll take it elsewhere.

Comment: I believe Andrei Gheorghiu did a great job explaining everything.  Thanks.  I wouldn't have figured it out without your precision.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, oh I see you were talking about reading comments on the question, not the ones on the answer. I always appreciate anyone's advice.